# how to pickle dump a dictionary and then load the dictionary back into the program to verify user/pass against?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm trying to save user input in the form of user/password to a dictionary. Pickle dump this dictionary and then during the login process, open the file, load the dictionary into the program and read from the dictionary to see if the user login matches that of the dictionary. the print statement is just to verify my dictionary is working. I can never tell if it's actually reading the file and loading the dictionary or just printing my user inputs from earlier.

```
import pickle

file = open("pckf.pck", "wb")

mydict = {"uname":[], "pword":[]}

#register
uname = input("Username: ")
pword = input("Password: ")
mydict["uname"].append(uname)
mydict["pword"].append(pword)

pickle.dump(mydict, file)
file.close()

#to-be login
file = open("pckf.pck", "rb")
pickle.load(file)
print(mydict)
```

Comment: It certainly is printing the user inputs from earlier, because *you threw away the data read from the file*.  Try `mynewdict = pickle.load(file)`; when you print that out, it should be obvious that it had to come from the file, because the name wasn't previously defined.

Comment: Great, that works. Silly error. So I was loading in my dictionary from file but then printing the inputs from earlier and ignoring the loaded dictionary? Just so I know for future what the actual issue was.